# AutoMapper and Entity Framework Include with circular relationships with No Tracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

Using Entity Framework 6, I'm trying to eagerly load my `Caller` models from the database using `.AsNoTracking()`, but I'm hitting a snag when I try to map these models to their ViewModels using AutoMapper 6.

The `Caller` has an `Address`, which is a many-to-one relationship (caller's can have one address, address can have multiple callers).

Here are the (reduced) model classes (ViewModels are nearly identical)

```
public class Caller
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public virtual  ICollection<Caller> Callers { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how I am mapping them

```
// Address
CreateMap<Address, AddressViewModel>()
    .ForMember(vm => vm.Id, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Id))
    .ForMember(vm => vm.CallerViewModels, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Callers))
    .ForMember(vm => vm.City, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.City))
    .ReverseMap();

// Caller
CreateMap<Caller, CallerViewModel>()
    .ForMember(vm => vm.Id, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Id))
    .ForMember(vm => vm.AddressViewModel, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Address))
    .ForMember(vm => vm.FirstName, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.FirstName))
    .ReverseMap();
```

In my `CallerRepository` I am using this function:

```
public async Task<Caller> GetFullCallerAsNoTrackingAsync(Guid id)
{
    return await _context.Callers
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(c => c.Address)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);
}
```

My problem happens here:

```
// Map Caller to a CallerViewModel
Caller caller = await unitOfWork.CallerRepo.GetFullCallerAsNoTrackingAsync(Guid.Parse(callerId));
CallerViewModel callerViewModel = Mapper.Map<CallerViewModel>(caller); // Throws exception
```

The exception that gets thrown says

> Error Mapping Types ... Caller.Address -> CallerViewModel.Address ... When an object is returned with a NoTracking merge option, Load can only be called when the EntityCollection or EntityReference does not contain objects.

This works just fine when I remove the `.AsNoTracking()`, but for performance reasons I'm trying to keep that in.

I don't need to know `Caller -> Address -> Callers`, I just need `Caller -> Address`

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

---

### Edit / Update:

Thanks to [FoundNil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50338857/1634205) I was able to get this done.

I changed my `Address` Map to:

```
    CreateMap<Address, AddressViewModel>()
        .ForMember(vm => vm.Id, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Id))
        .ForMember(vm => vm.CallerViewModels, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Callers).Ignore())
        .ForMember(vm => vm.City, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.City))
        .ReverseMap();
```

And I did the same to a different property, `CallDetailViewModels`, on my `Caller -> CallerViewModel` map

```
    CreateMap<Caller, CallerViewModel>()
        .ForMember(vm => vm.Id, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Id))
        .ForMember(vm => vm.AddressViewModel, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Address))
        .ForMember(vm => vm.CallDetailViewModels, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.CallDetails).Ignore())
```

The similarities I see between this and `Address` is that `Caller` is the parent object of `Address`, and `CallDetail` is the parent object of `Caller`

Both of these parents were navigation properties in their respective Model class:

```
Caller -> public virtual ICollection<CallDetail> CallDetails { get; set; }
Address -> public virtual ICollection<Caller> Callers { get; set; }
```

Perhaps this might give a useful flag to others of where they might encounter this problem.

*Note:* My `CallDetail` has a many-to-many relationship with `Caller`, so it also has a navigation property of `Callers`, and I'm not ignoring that in my `CallDetail` Map.

Comment: I think this is have nothing to do with AutoMapper. If you search the error message you'll see that it exists a lot anwser which states that to work well with AsNotTracking you should also disable the proxy generation of EF. I let you test after you can put your own answer :)

Comment: Why not use ProjectTo instead. An then you don't need Include or AsNoTracking.

Comment: Changing my `GetFullCallerAsNoTrackingAsync` to use `.ProjectTo<CallerViewModel>()` throws an error saying: `Type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable\`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]' does not have a default constructor` My CallerViewModel has a couple `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for DropDowns. Not sure how to fix this just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why its happening, but I would guess the problem is that when you use `.AsNoTracking()` something happens between `Address -> Callers` in the context, so there is no longer a way to map `ICollection<Caller>` and its view model.

And since you mentioned you only want `Caller -> Address` you should try this map:

```
// Address
CreateMap<Address, AddressViewModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Callers, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ReverseMap();

// Caller
CreateMap<Caller, CallerViewModel>()
    .ForMember(vm => vm.AddressViewModel, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Address))
    .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: This has certainly gotten me further! I'm checking now to see if it's viable in my system for the other components. It's nearing end of day for me, so I'll likely get back to you on if this works or not for me tomorrow.

Comment: This did it! I did have to go through and do this to a few of my other related Mappings, but I got what I wanted, thank you!

Comment: @RyanTaite Glad I could help!